# Seems like props is taking too long to load in react functional component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a functional component that takes in some props. One of these props is a list of ID's. I use these ID's to get the data from the backend service. Its a simple component to show the number of messages per user and makes use of google charts.

```
export const MessageChart = (props) => {
    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]); 

    const createData = async () => {
        let obj = {Year_Duration: "Messages"};
        let message_data = [];
        let array_data = [];

        for(let i=0;i<props.data.length;i++){
            await api.get('/usermessagestats/'+props.data[i]).then(result => {
                let found_data = result.data[0];
                if(props.name == undefined){
                    if(!(found_data.duration_title in obj)){
                        obj[found_data.duration_title] = found_data.number_of_messages;
                    }else{
                        obj[found_data.duration_title]  = obj[found_data.duration_title] + found_data.number_of_messages;
                    }
                }
                else if (props.name == result.data[0].user){
                    message_data.push(result.data[0]);
                    if(!(found_data.duration_title in obj)){
                        obj[found_data.duration_title] = found_data.number_of_messages;
                    }else{
                        obj[found_data.duration_title]  = obj[found_data.duration_title] + found_data.number_of_messages;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        Object.entries(obj).map(value => {
            array_data.push(value);
        });
        
        setChartData(array_data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        createData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <ChartBox>

            <Chart
                width={'100%'}
                height={'100%'}
                chartType="ColumnChart"
                loader={<CircularProgress />}
                data={chartData}
                options={{
                    legend: { position: 'none' },
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Messages',
                        subtitle: 'Per year',
                    },
                    colors: [colours.chartBars],
                    backgroundColor: colours.box,
                    hAxis: {
                        textStyle: {
                            color: colours.chartText
                          }
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        textStyle: {
                            color: colours.chartText
                          }
                    }
                }}
            />
            <button onClick={createData}>check if chart works</button>
        </ChartBox>
    )
}
```

The prop with the list of ID's is called data.
The problem I have is when I load the page and load the component I get and error in the for loop saying that it cannot read props.data.length and that it is undefined. However if I exit the error and press the button to test if the data shows up it works? So the data prop (list of ID's) definitely exists but I can't use it until a few seconds have passed for some reason.

Now I'm a React beginner so I could just be using React wrong but it seems like the prop is taking a long time to be passed to the component?

ChartBoxi s just a styled component so it can be ignored.
I am using the latest version of React.

Comment: What do u have in props.data initially ? It seems u need yo check if there us props.data then do all the function.. something like: if props.data {all thr for loop...}

Comment: props are not passed as a stream, they are initialized in the initialization phase of component, you could watch for props changes in the useEffect and to run the createData function only if (props.data && props.data.length > 0)

Comment: @RoeiGrinshpan the props.data is just an array containing numbers which are ID's. I have already checked to see if it is empty and it never is. Therefore the length of the array must be > 0. So the loop should run? However, react tells me that props.data is undefined but if I wait a few seconds its available and i'm not sure why?

Comment: @Alopwer Thank you very much for the advice, it worked!